# Jetty9 How to properly close the WebSocketClient@ thread problem?

Tags: java, jetty, end-of-life

**Jetty Version**
Jetty 9.4.53

**Jetty Environment**
linux
jetty run command: ./bin/jetty.sh run

**Java Version**
1.8.0_371   x64

**Question**
I used this code to create a Websocket client connection

```
WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
container.connectToServer(this, URI.create(url));
```

If the server connection fails, this code will continue to be used during the reconnection.
But each execution of this code creates eight threads of ***WebSocketClient@xxx-xxx***
The connection pool cannot be automatically destroyed if the connection fails.
My code `ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();`
-> `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.ClientContainer`<111 line> - > `public ClientContainer()`
->  `WebSocketClient` <95 line>-> `public WebSocketClient()`
-> `DefaultHttpClientProvider.get` 
-> `DefaultHttpClientProvider.newHttpClient`

**Reconnecting will create a new thread pool and 8 threads. How do I close this object? Can't you create a Websocket client this way in Jetty?**

[thread image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwHcn.png)

How to properly close the WebSocketClient@ thread problem?

Comment: Jetty 9 is at End of Life, you should upgrade to a supported version of Jetty.  See also https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/issues/2659#issuecomment-421455571 (which points out that javax.websocket has no close/stop behavior)

Answer (score 0):

The Jakarta WebSocket Client Container (aka `jakarta.websocket.WebSocketContainer`, or the older now deprecated and end-of-life `javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer`) is meant to be started only once, and you use that container over and over again until the JVM exits.

You don't create the container for each request.

You treat the container as you would a web browser you open only 1 web browser and use it to access many different sites.

This design decision by Jakarta EE WebSocket is intentional, as such there is no close/stop/shutdown API for the WebSocketContainer.

If you want to reconnect, just use one of the `connectToServer()` methods again.

There was an issue opened back in 2013 against the Jakarta EE WebSocket Spec to define such an API, but there's been no traction or interest in developing such an API.
https://github.com/jakartaee/websocket/issues/212